# What is more recommended to use in the C Driver , mongoc_collection_command with "insert" or mongoc_collection_insert

Tags: mongodb

After working for awhile with the C driver , reading the tutorials and the API . 
I little confused ,
According to this tutorial : http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/executing-command.html
i can execute DB and Collections commands which include also the CRUD commands.
And i can even get the Document cursor if i don't use "_simple" in the command API
so why do i need to use for example the mongoc_collection_insert() API command ?
What are the differences ? what is recommended ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is probably similar to what's the difference between using [insert command](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/insert/) or [db.collection.insert()](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/) via the mongo shell.

[mongoc_collection_insert()](http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/mongoc_collection_insert.html) is specific function written to insert a document into a collection while [mongoc_collection_command()](http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/mongoc_collection_command.html) is for executing any valid [database commands](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/) on a collection.

I would recommend to use the API function (`mongoc_collection_insert`) whenever possible. For the following reasons:

- The API functions had been written as an abstraction layer with a specific purpose so that you don't have to deal with other details related to the command.

  For example, `mongoc_collection_insert` exposes the right parameters for inserting i.e. [mongoc_write_concern_t](http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/mongoc_write_concern_t.html) and [mongoc_insert_flags_t](http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/mongoc_insert_flags_t.html) with the respective default value. On the other hand, `mongoc_collection_command` has broad range of parameters such as [mongoc_read_prefs_t](http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/mongoc_read_prefs_t.html), `skip`, or `limit` which may not be relevant for inserting a document.
- Any future changes for `mongoc_collection_insert` will more likely be considered with the correct context for insert.
- Especially for CRUD, try to avoid using command because the [MongoDB wire protocol](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-wire-protocol/) specifies different [request opcodes](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-wire-protocol/#request-opcodes) for command (OP_MSG: 1000) and insert (OP_INSERT: 2002).